# Updating the state with fetched data but when trying to console.log it gives 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state, store

When I fetch data on render or on change of some dependencies it updates in Redux store properly but when console.loging it gives 'undeifined'.

I am developing booking system and want to fetch already booked hours on specified day

```
/// Fetch data on render the component and try to console.log
     useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://localhost/healthboyz/index.php/booked/${
          formData.doctor_id
        }/${moment(formData.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}`
      )
      .then((res) => setBookedHrs(res.data))
      .then(() => console.log(bookedHrs))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));}, 
    [formData.doctor_id, formData.date]);
```

```
/// Hours reducer 
 const hoursReducerDefaultState: {
  bookedHrs: string[];
} = {
  bookedHrs: [],
};

export const hoursReducer = (
  state = hoursReducerDefaultState,
  action: {
    type: string;
    data: string[];
  }
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_BOOKED_HRS':
      return [...action.data];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: It looks as though you may need to `return { bookedHrs: action.data };` in the `hoursReducer` action unless the `hoursReducer` is actually `hoursReducerDefaultState["bookedHrs"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is actually to do with how the state is being set in Redux:

Assuming that the `hoursReducer` is responsible for the whole of `hoursReducerDefaultState` which is:

```js
type HoursReducer = {
  bookedHrs: string[];
};

 const hoursReducerDefaultState: HoursReducer = {
  bookedHrs: [],
};
```

You then need to set the Redux state to update state you are aiming to update:

```js
export const hoursReducer = (
  state = hoursReducerDefaultState,
  action: {
    type: string;
    data: string[];
  }
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_BOOKED_HRS':
      // Remember to include the previous state using the "spread" operator
      return {
        ...state,
        bookedHrs: action.data
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Note: I'm also assuming that you want to fully replace the value of `bookedHrs`.

Comment: This completly solve all of my questions. Thank you very much!